# Python input() blocks subprocesses from executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a Python script that accepts user input. Different user inputs trigger different functionality. The functionality in question here is one that spawns multiple processes. Here is the script, `main.py`.

```
import time
import threading
import concurrent.futures as cf


def executeparallelprocesses():

    numprocesses = 2
    durationseconds = 10

    futures = []

    print('Submit jobs as new processes.')
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=numprocesses) as executor:
        for i in range(numprocesses):
            futures.append(executor.submit(workcpu, 500, durationseconds))
            print('job submitted')
        print('all jobs submitted')

        print('Wait for jobs to complete.', flush=True)
        for future in cf.as_completed(futures):
            future.result()

        print('All jobs done.', flush=True)


def workcpu(x, durationseconds):
    print('Job executing in new process.')
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < durationseconds:
        x * x


def main():

    while True:
        cmd = input('Press ENTER\n')
        if cmd == 'q':
            break
        thread = threading.Thread(target=executeparallelprocesses)
        thread.start()

    time.sleep(15)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When this script is invoked from the terminal, it works as expected (i.e., the subprocesses execute). Specifically, notice the two lines "Job executing in new process." in the example run that follows:

```
(terminal prompt $) python3 main.py
Press ENTER

Submit jobs as new processes.
Press ENTER
job submitted
job submitted
all jobs submitted
Wait for jobs to complete.
Job executing in new process.
Job executing in new process.
All jobs done.
q
(terminal prompt $)
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
When the script is invoked from another program, the subprocesses are not executed. Here is the driver script, `driver.py`:

```
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE


args = ['python3', 'main.py']

p = subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

time.sleep(1)

print('', file=p.stdin, flush=True)

time.sleep(1)

print('q', file=p.stdin, flush=True)

time.sleep(20)
```

Notice how "Job executing in new process." is not present in the output from the example run that follows:

```
(terminal prompt $) python3 driver.py
Press ENTER
Submit jobs as new processes.
Press ENTER
job submitted
job submitted
all jobs submitted
Wait for jobs to complete.
(terminal prompt $)
```

It seems like the `cmd = input('Press ENTER\n')` statement in `main.py` is blocking and preventing the subprocesses from executing. Strangely, commenting out the second `time.sleep(1)` statement in `driver.py` causes the `main.py` subprocesses to spawn as expected. Another way to make this "work" is to add `time.sleep(1)` inside the loop of `main.py`, right after `thread.start()`.

This time-sensitive code is brittle. Is there a robust way to do this?

Comment: Please **always** use a generic [python] tag for **all** python-related questions. Note, Python 3 is what is assumed, Python 2 has passed it's official end of life.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think tagging as python-3.x (as well as python) is probably going to continue for a while; Py2 may be EOL, but classes are still being taught in it, sadly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger sure, but at the very least, there should *always* be a [python] tag

Comment: Not sure which, if any of these, are the problem, but a few notes: 1) Leaving off `flush=True` when you do `print('Job executing in new process.')` can mean stuff gets stuck in worker process buffers. 2) Mixing threads and worker processes is a bad idea, especially if you're on a non-Windows system where the default start method is `'fork'`. Add a `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` (or `'forkserver'`) after `if __name__ == '__main__':` to avoid the major issues there. 3) Combining `bufsize=0` with `universal_newlines=True` doesn't work; `bufsize=1` is best you can do with text mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried ShadowRanger's suggestion to add a call to `multiprocessing.set_start_method()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    main()
```

This solved the problem for me. I will read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you try to communicate with the second script using `stdin=PIPE` - try the following instead for the second script:

```py
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE


args = ['python', 'junk.py']

p = subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

p.communicate(input='\nq\n')

time.sleep(20)
```

Output:

```
Press ENTER
Submit jobs as new processes.
Press ENTER
job submitted
job submitted
all jobs submitted
Wait for jobs to complete.
Job executing in new process.
Job executing in new process.
All jobs done.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note that, instead of inserting timeouts everywhere, you should probably look in to joining completed processes, but that goes beyond the question.